# Relation between $\overline{Y}$ and $Y^{\perp}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

Let $Y$ be a subspace of a normed vector space $X$. Let $Y^{\perp}$ be the space of all $\lambda \in X^{\ast}$ which vanish on $Y$. Why is $\overline{Y} = \{x \in X: \lambda(x) = 0 \text{ for all } \lambda \in Y^{\perp}\}$. The set on the right hand side is closed and contains $Y$. But why is this the smallest closed set that contains $Y$?

Comment: Can you show that $\overline{Y}=(Y^\perp)^\perp$ (at least, I think that's true, if I recall correctly)?

Comment: It's true for Hilbert spaces, but I'm not sure if it's true for general normed vector spaces.

Comment: Yes, I remember now. Thanks.

Comment: A little question on your notation convention: is $X^\ast$ topological or algrebraic dual?

Comment: $X^{\ast}$ is the algebraic dual.

Comment: @qki It must be the topological dual, for the algebraic dual, $$\bigcap_{\lambda \in Y^\perp} \ker\lambda = Y.$$ And: Hahn-Banach.

Answer (score 0):

To prove the inclusion $\overline{Y}\subset\{x\in X:\lambda (x)=0$ for all $\lambda \in Y^{\perp}\} $ let $y\in \overline{Y}$. Then there exists a sequence $(y_n)$ in $Y$ with $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} y_n = y$. For all $\lambda \in Y^{\perp}$ we have by continuity: $\lambda (y) = \lambda (\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} y_n) = \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \lambda (y_n) = 0$.